# Sorting Objects in a relationship by an attribute?

Tags: swift, sorting

I am attempting to created a sort function that will order objects accessed via a relationship with a parent object by dateCreated attribute. Hoping that the result will provide me with a set of objects I can load into my tableview.

I understand that ill need to use a sort function, and convert their NSDate attribute to a timestamp to be able to compare as they arent simple date attributes.

However I am unsure how i would go about accessing these attributes to begin with. Ive had a shot at the code based on my reading but its throwing errors and I cant get my head around resolving it.

```
        if let userExercise = selectedRoutine?.userexercises?.allObjects[indexPath.row] {

        let dateSortedUserExercises = userExercise.sorted (by: { (left, right) -> Bool in
            userExercise.dateCreated!.timeIntervalSince1970 > userExercise.dateCreated!.timeIntervalSince1970
        })
        print("SORTED EXERCISES \(dateSortedUserExercises)")
```

Im getting:

> Value of type 'Any' has no member 'sorted'

then if i make it `(userExercise as AnyObject)` as recommended by swift, i get

> Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'sorted'

I believe im either taking a wrong route here or im accessing the wrong things the wrong way? Thanks for any assistance here!

update: added screenshot mentioned below

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4ad7.png)

Comment: `userExercise` (which should be called `userExercises`, btw, because it's a collection of user exercises, not just a single one) must be cast to a Sequence (such as an Array) in order to have the `sorted` method.

Comment: I see, do you have any more information on this as I haven't used this method previously

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why did you create a new account?

Comment: i wanted to change the name as the other wasn't very professional!

Comment: @jwarris91 You can do that without creating a new account..

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the two objects in the closure when sorting.

```
let dateSortedUserExercises = userExercise.sorted { left, right in
        left.dateCreated!.timeIntervalSince1970 > right.dateCreated!.timeIntervalSince1970
    }
```

or in a more concise format:

```
let dateSortedUserExercises = userExercise.sorted { $0.0.dateCreated!.timeIntervalSince1970 > $0.1.dateCreated!.timeIntervalSince1970 }
```

where $0.0 is the left side and $0.1 is the right side.

Comment: thanks for this, im still getting a similar error of "Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'sorted'"

Comment: go to your .xcdatamodelId file, and in the model entity inspector set the class to your class name. That should associate that model with that class

Comment: thats not resolving the issue, its a trickier situation in the context of the code, essentially i take the selectedRoutine and go via its relationship to the objects (the exercises to sort) so userExercises are the exercise objects, but not seemingly in the straight forward way you would expect. They are already set as UserExercise in the datamodel file but casing userExercise as! UserExercse (which should be the same thing) throws a lot more errors, ill update the OP to show

Comment: This is really a core data issue, Core Data changed significantly in swift 3 and I am not really familiar enough with it to give you any suggestions with confidence. There is a lot of stuff out there now on how to handle getting types from your managedObject subclasses. if your not fetching them properly you don't get the proper type. You need to make a fetch request similar to this 'let fetchRequest =
    NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "UserExercises")'. Check out other swift 3 core data posts on getting properly typed objects

Comment: in this instance a fetch request wouldnt be appropriate as i load the object via being passed from a previous controller that has a fetch request of routines, changing this in this VC entirely undermines the current code and would need a substantial rewrite to use it as you proposed, hence why i posed this question to see if it could be avoided

Comment: your question title, tags, and code sample mention sorting. If your issue is about core data and fetch requests, I suggest you open a new question with a clearer indication of what you are having issues with.

Comment: perhaps my oversight, i meant the term 'attribute' in the title to relate to a coredata entity attribute